# Use AVSpeechSynthesizer on iOS 7 but retain compatibility for iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

Hello I Understand TTS is only available in iOS 7 but i used many apis in the past by checking if the class is available and managed to retain compatibility on previous versions but with AVSpeechSynthesizer it doesn't seem to work, can you please help me use TTS for iOS 7 and retain compatibility by disabling it in iOS 6, thank you very much.

Here is my code but it doesn't seem to work

```
    if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)) {
    if([AVSpeechSynthesizer class]) {
        AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
        AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:text];
        utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];
        utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate/2;
        utterance.pitchMultiplier = 0.9;
        utterance.preUtteranceDelay = 0;
        utterance.postUtteranceDelay = 0;
        [synth speakUtterance:utterance];
    } else {
        // Feature not available, do something else
    }
}
```

i've already linked avfoundation in my project and set deployment target iOS 6 and it seems to work only when runing on iOS 7 devices if its iOS 6 it crashes.

here is the error message i get

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
```

Comment: Did you weak link the framework?

Comment: Go to "Build Phases" and change "AVFundation" from Required to Optional... and Voila!

Answer (score 6):

The framework needs to be be weak linked. Do the following:

1. Click your project file in the Project Navigator (on the left) to open your project in the editor
2. Click the **Build Phases** tab in the editor
3. Expand the **Link Binary With Libraries** section
4. Set **AVFoundation.framework** from **Required** to **Optional**

[image: Setting AVFoundation.framework from Required to Optional]

Additionally, you might want to update your version check with [one that's safer](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-check-the-ios-version-in-an-app/) (and recommended by Apple).

Comment: Did you sow our comms? Why is your answer different?  :)

Comment: @TonyMkenu The point of Stack Overflow, as I see it, is for someone to come and find an answer to their question. If there are no actual answers to the question, and only comments, someone might miss that there's a solution to this problem.