# Disable some classes when building on ios6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I am using an application that contains some classes supported on ios7 and cause crashing when launching the app on ios6
So i am trying to find a way to disable these classes(some functions in these classes) when building on ios6 target but still can't find anything useful on the internet.
i tired the following link:

[How to execute a block of code in IOS7 not in IOS6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020244/how-to-execute-a-block-of-code-in-ios7-not-in-ios6?rq=1) 
but not worked for me and the app still crahed on startup.

Also,

I tried to use the following for the defined classes

```
#define IS_IOS7 (([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion intValue] > 6)?64:0)
if(IS_IOS7)
{
//classes definition
}
```

but still without any success and the application continue crashing on launching.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Dear @borrrden ..i tried that link but not worked in my case!!

Comment: Did you check the duplicate of that question as well?

Comment: @borrrden, yes it is the first thing i tried because  i use that method in all my application, but in the case where the class is not supported by ios6 will not work!

Comment: It most definitely will work, as many others have shown.  Perhaps you should make a new question detailing the crash (error messages, etc).

Comment: Only thing shown in debug are: dyld: Symbol not found: _AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
  Referenced from: /Users/zhf/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/4A005E97-6DB5-49A4-B674-967BD553A47A/Broders.app/Broders
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
 in /Users/zhf/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/4A005E97-6DB5-49A4-B674-967BD553A47A/Broders.app/Broders and the app crash after it

Comment: i have simplified my code to 1 line to test it :
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
            // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
        } else {
  CGFloat _utteranceRate;
        _utteranceRate = (AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate + AVSpeechUtteranceMinimumSpeechRate) / 2.0;
        }

If i comment that line the application will work..the above code will crash

Comment: @borrrden Finally after 4 days of searching if found my solution here in case anyone will benefit from my comment
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102500/use-avspeechsynthesizer-on-ios-7-but-retain-compatibility-for-ios-6
Thank you anw for your corporation:)